# Why does UISegementedControl's setTitleTextAttributes only change the text color but not the font face/weight for active state?

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

With the following code I try to change the appearance of a UISegmentedControl, but only the text color changes with highlighted or selected tabs. Font face and weight are taken from the inactive attributes, so that all parts of the segmented control show Futura-Medium on the title label, no matter if highlighted, selected or normal. Why is this?

```
NSDictionary *attributesActive = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter-Bold" size:22.f], UITextAttributeFont,
        [UIColor redColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
        [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
        nil];
NSDictionary *attributesInactive = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura-Medium" size:16.f], UITextAttributeFont,
        [UIColor greenColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
        [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
        nil];

[segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributesActive forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributesActive forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributesInactive forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```